# Filling a combo box with mysql data

Tags: java, mysql

hi everyone i have this code but don't know why it doesn't work!

```
//in database class 

String query = "SELECT group_name FROM customer ORDER BY group_name"; 
java.sql.PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query); 

rs = stm.executeQuery(query); 

while (rs.next()) { 
String x = rs.getString("group_name"); 
System.out.println(x); 
} 

rs.close(); 
} 


//combo box action 


int group = jcombobox.getSelectedIndex(); 

rg_domain rg = new rg_domain(); 
rg.setGroup(group); 
rg.setPhone_number(phone_no); 

dbconnection db = new dbconnection(); 

db.broadcastmsgservice_sms(rg); 
} 


//domain class 
 private String group;
public void setGroup(String group) { 
this.group = group; 
} 
public String getGroup() { 
return group; 
}
```

can anyone help me please..

Comment: @Luzhin there's no any error message.but it doesn't fill the combo box with mysql table data.

Comment: Seems that you are completely lost here. You are just traversing the `ResultSet`. You are utilizing these values in the `while` loop.

Comment: you have to add value to Array of JList inside while (rs.next()) { ...

Comment: @Luzhin , @Talha_Ahmed_Khan , @Behrang_Saeedzadeh Thank you very much for helping me. I solved my problem with all of your help.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is not very clear, but here's how you fill a combo box with results retrieved from the database:

```
// Create an array list to be filled with group names
ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "SELECT group_name FROM customer ORDER BY group_name"; 
PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query); 

ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query); 

while (rs.next()) { 
    String groupName = rs.getString("group_name"); 
    // add group names to the array list
    groupNames.add(groupName)
} 

rs.close(); 


// Populate the combo box
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(groupNames.toArray());
comboBox.setModel(model);
```